# Git Untracked Working Tree Tile

Tags: git

On a remote repo, I am trying to do a pull to get updates from the central repo.
Strangely, I get

```
error: Untracked working tree file '.htaccess' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting
```

My .`gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` contains `.htaccess`.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have that `.htaccess` file in your local Git repo and its untracked since it matches the pattern you have in `.gitignore`. At the same time, the file is in the remote central Git repo. Therefore, Git warns you that pulling the changes will overwrite the `.htaccess` in your local repo.

You can

- remove `.htaccess` in the remote repo. It's in `gitignore` after all.
- remove `.htaccess` in your repo.
- force the pull by issuing [`git pull --force`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).

Adding an item to `gitignore` does not remove it from the repository. It just prevents it from being added and tracked. So if `htaccess` is already in the repo, you have to remove it first before adding to `gitignore`.

Read the [documentation on gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git
>   should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected ...